# After 14.04 --> 16.04 upgrade, Gnome desktop will not start; only have a console login

Tags: gnome, upgrade

After the upgrade yesterday on boot I only have a console login. This link shows that gdm is running and has been:  https://pastebin.com/UvpNmsSw

Here is the link to my dmesg log  https://pastebin.com/EhbmQB5C

I'm running kernel 4.4.0-31-generic dated 13 July.

I've just noticed that my Xorg.0.log is a mess. Its timestamp is 6pm today https://pastebin.com/R7xeQf3w

Link to Xorg log after upgrade yesterday https://pastebin.com/c9DUXzuk

I'd be happy to supply any other files or logs. This is really bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- type "startx" in console
- Ctrl+Alt+F7 or other F# combination

Comment: startx drops down a line then says 'timeout waiting for.Xauthority then display goes black. I copied the Xorg.1.log file to Xorg.0.log and restarted. As its booting I see no 'fail' entries. Still drops to a console login. All the ctrl-alt F7-12 do is put a blinking cursor in the upper left hand corner.

Comment: Hi, I'll let you know if I figured a way.

Comment: thank you. I'm thinking about installing kde just to see if it will boot into it. At least I can use Lynx for Google and I found a txt based IRC client.

Comment: I have managed to get the system pretty much functional. Here is what I did:  I installed 'ubuntu-gnome-desktop'; installed outdated 'xserver-xorg-core; libegli-mesa; libgbmi; libgli-mesa-dri; libgli-mesa-glx; libglapi-mesa. I removed ~/.Xauthority as I was getting a file locking error. Not sure why it was owned by root anyway.  I overwrote the existing 4.4.0-28 kernel with the one for 14.04. When I rebooted it was updated to the current Xenial 4.4.0-28. I was alerted of firmware missing: /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1.bin; bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin; skl_guc_ver6_1.bin.

Comment: System still boots to console however ctrl-alt-F7 does bring up the Gnome Desktop after a bit of delay. Still not understanding why the system will not boot directly into Gnome.

Comment: Other than some errors during boot that I need to find out what they mean the system appears to be up now. One note - when booking just the kernel, not the 'upstart' version once the console login appears waiting for about 3-4 minutes seems to work with bringing up the Gnome desktop. When booting with the 'upstart' kernel it boots right into Gnome as you'd expect.  One problem I do have is getting 'courier-authdaemon' to start on boot. Just something I'll have to figure out. For now I'd have to say this problem is resolved.

Comment: Hi, Glad to hear it functional now.